# <select> Options change without AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**Question**

I have two `<select>` inputs, the first one being `country` and the second one being a more specific location. So if you set the `country` to `United Kingdom` you'll receive all the options that are under `United Kingdom` in the database.

I know this would be pretty simple with `AJAX` however, I do not want to use `AJAX`.

```
require_once("func/connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM site_locations";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

}

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Country</label>
    <div>
        <select class="form-control" name="country"  required>
        <?php include('includes/country_list.php');?>
        <!-- Here is where the countries are selected -->
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Specific Site Location</label>
    <div>
        <select class="form-control" required name="site">
            <option></option>
            <!-- Here to set the options -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Thoughts on a solution**

Create an array of countries with sub-arrays of the locations then if it is selected say `United Kingdom` then javascript can update the `site locations` with all the locations from the array.

Alternatively I'll have to use AJAX but I really don't want to.

Comment: You will have to store all the information in javascript. and update the select according to the selected country.

Comment: What's wrong with using ajax?

Comment: How big is the data-set we're talking about, because if it's a list of all cities in every single country, AJAX is your only _real_ option here, but if you want, you can generate a JS object that has country names as properties, and its locations as a value array: `var locationMap = <?php echo json_encode($theData); ?>;` where `$theData` looks something like `['countryName' => ['city1', 'city2']]` and so on

Comment: what you thinking is the only solution. you'll need a big javascript array there. also, what A. Wolff said.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem currently it's not very big however that could change in the future, I imagine no more than 100-200 total

Comment: @Danny123: In that case, use AJAX anyway, if you don't you're going to have to send the full data-set for every page request, which is something you'll want to avoid

Comment: I've done things like this before, but as @EliasVanOotegem and @KatrinRaimond alluded to, it's really size-dependant. Getting the info on the page is easy though `<script type="application/javascript">var myArray=<?php echo json_encode($myArray) ?>;</script>

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The only problem with that is how will I separate the search to loop and add `$theData` when these will be selected from the database randomly or `ORDER BY country` However, I will still need about 196 different searches to add them correctly or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: Cheers guys, I guess AJAX is the only way for a database search like this

Comment: @Danny123 the AJAX option is to listen to the change event on the 1st select, grab the ID of the country that was selected, AJAX that off to get the options to shown for the 2nd select and put them in place.. it's really quite easy, but very dependant on how you have things set up.

Comment: please checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/

Comment: thank u! Shall i post this as answer then

Comment: @Sudarshan: Please, don't use `new Array` in JS... just don't

Comment: Why does it takes more time??

Comment: @Danny123 please tell me that fiddle helped u?

Comment: @Sudarshan: It's slightly longer to type than `var anArray = [];` and it's slightly more error prone: `var myArray = [12];` is an array with 1 value (12), whereas `var weirdArray = new Array(12);` is an array with 12 keys, each holding the value `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a purely theoretical answer to your question would look like this:

```
$locations = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if (!isset($locations[$row['country']])
    {
        $locations[$row['country']] = [];
    }
    $locations[$row['country']][] = $row['location'];
}
```

Then, to populate the country select element:

```
$countries = array_keys($locations);
foreach ($countries as $country)
{
    echo '<option value="' . $country . '">' . $country . '</option>';
}
```

And to make the locations map available to your JS code, simply write this:

```
var locationsMap = <?php ech json_encode($locations); ?>;
```

Lastly, attach an event listener to the country select element, that populates the locations element on the *change* event, and you're done

But that's all just theory, in practice:

## Use AJAX, this type of responsiveness is exactly what it's for

Using AJAX, all you have to do is attach the same event listener (change on the country element), and pass the selected value to an AJAX request, that returns the values that should be used to populate the locations element:

```
<select class="form-control" id="country" name="country"  required>
    <!-- populate whichever way you want -->
</select>
```

then:

```
document.querySelector('#country').addEventListener('change', function(e)
{
    //if you want to support very old browsers
    e = e || window.event;
    var country = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;//or .text
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('post', 'yourUrl', true);
    req.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState===4 && this.status===200)
        {//assuming the AJAX request returns the options for locations element:
            document.querySelector('#locations').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    req.send('country=' + country);//send selected value
});
//or with jQuery:
$('#country').on('change', function()
{
    var data = {country: $(this).val()};
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourUrl',
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function(r)
        {
            $('#locations').html(r);//<-- something like that
        }
    });
});
```

*Note:*
It's been quite some time since I last did some front-end stuff, and I wrote this off the top of my head, so this is not a copy-pastable piece of code. It's also far from optimized, but it should be enough to get you started.

PS: you linked to w3schools in your comment, you might want to check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) instead. They still tend to offer up better, and more complete documentation for all things JS

Comment: I think I'll have to use ajax, so will I do something similar to this -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: @Danny123: I'll add a simplistic/generic JS example of how I'd use ajax in this case to my answer, for completeness' sake

Comment: @Danny123 I will suggest you to make use of jquery ajax rather than core ajax. Since it is realy simple to use and easy to maintain.

Comment: @HarigovindR http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load something like this ?

Comment: @Danny123: Updated my JS example, added a jQuery snippet. I'm not a big jQ fan, but in this case, it does make for cleaner code

Comment: @Danny123: You're welcome, +1 on your question on the basis that you actually listened to the suggestions people made, and are willing to try/learn new things. An attitude that not enough people have on SO, sadly

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Just one last question ( I promise ).. In the .php file that will output the `post` should I output them as `<option value="#">#</option>` or as an json array?

Comment: That really depends. If you generate `<option value="%s">%s</option>`, then you can simply replace the inner HTML using JS (like I did in my example code). If you return them as an array, you'll have to `json_encode` it before echoing the data, then `JSON.parse(r);` the response in JS, and iterate over it, generating the HTML client-side. The choice is yours, really

Comment: @Danny123 try something like this [jquery ajax example](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html)

Comment: @HarigovindR I've got my script working just how I want it now, thank you very much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. However I recommended to use AJAX instead...

```
<form method = "post">
     <select name="country" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value='a'>A</option>
        <option value='b'>B</option>
        <option value='C'>C</option> 
        .....
    </select>

    <select name="location">
      <?php 
         if(isset( $_POST['country'] )){
          //code here to fetch relevant data
         }
      ?>
    </select>

</form>
```

Comment: That's even worse than the 2 options the OP is talking about, That, and there's little difference between a complete form submit and a partial one using AJAX, apart from the AJAX request being smaller, simpler and faster in every possible way

Comment: To get a set $_POST then it would require a POST which is what I'm trying to avoid.